# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SwiftyStoreKit.framework/Versions/A/SwiftyStoreKit - macCatalyst

Tags: macos, cocoapods, mac-catalyst, swiftystorekit

Run fails with the error for `mac Catalyst`

```
require 'cocoapods-catalyst-support'
 platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'MyApp' do
 use_frameworks!

pod 'SwiftyStoreKit'
end

# Configure your macCatalyst dependencies
catalyst_configuration do
    # Uncomment the next line for a verbose output
     verbose!

    # ios '<pod_name>' # This dependency will only be available for iOS
    # macos '<pod_name>' # This dependency will only be available for macOS
end

post_install do |installer|

    installer.configure_catalyst
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY'] = 'No'
      config.build_settings['ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES'] = 'Yes'
     end
  end
end
end
```

This is my `podfile` ,ya this contains more pods other. than `SwiftyStoreKit`.
i am able to run without the `SwiftyStoreKit`, but if i add at then getting this error and breakpoint

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SwiftyStoreKit.framework/Versions/A/SwiftyStoreKit
  Referenced from: /Users/admin/Library/Caches/...../Build/Products/Debug-maccatalyst/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp
  Reason: image not found
```

i am using this tool to exclude pods for mac catalyst: https://github.com/fermoya/cocoapods-catalyst-support

using

Xcode : 12.4
macOS : Big Sur 11.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrating `SwiftStoreKit` with **Swift Package Manager** solves the issue.

If you are using Xcode 11 or later:

1. Click File
2. Swift Packages
3. Add Package Dependency...
4. Specify the git URL for SwiftyStoreKit.

https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit.git